# shinyjs: toggle doesn't hide custom UI when condition does not evaluate to TRUE

Tags: r, shiny, toggle, shinydashboard, shinyjs

I'm playing with `shinyjs` pkg and various options for hiding/showing custom UI. In the app below I want to show selected plots and if no option is selected, display an empty space. I use `toggle()`, which does the trick as long as at least one option in `checkboxGroupInput` is selected, but when no option is chosen both plots are displayed. According to [documentation](https://rdrr.io/cran/shinyjs/man/visibilityFuncs.html):

> If condition is given to toggle, that condition will be used to
>   determine if to show or hide the element. The element will be shown if
>   the condition evaluates to TRUE and hidden otherwise.

Am I missing something obvious here?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(ggplot2)

ui <-dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs(),
    checkboxGroupInput(inputId = 'options',
                       label = 'Choose your plot(s)',
                       choices = list("Plot 1" = 1,
                                      "Plot2" = 2)),
                       #selected = 1:2),
    verbatimTextOutput('checkbox_text'),
        uiOutput("Ui1"),
        uiOutput('Ui2')
        )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$checkbox_text <- renderText({
    paste(input$options)
  })


    observe({
    shinyjs::toggle(id = "Ui1", condition = input$options == 1)
    shinyjs::toggle(id = "Ui2", condition = input$options == 2)
  })

  output$Ui1 <- renderUI({

    output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
      p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, mpg)) +
        geom_point() +
        geom_smooth() +
        ggtitle('Plot 1')
      p  
    })

    plotOutput('plot1')
  })

  output$Ui2 <- renderUI({

    output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
      p<- ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, mpg, colour = as.factor(cyl))) +
        geom_point() +
        ggtitle('Plot 2')
      p
    })

    plotOutput('plot2')
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're looking for which boxes are checked in `checkboxGroupInput` it's generally better to do evaluations of whether the value you're interested in is equal to any of the values in `checkboxGroupInput` - replacing your `observe` statement with this will fix the issue:

```
  observe({
    shinyjs::toggle(id = "Ui1", condition = {1 %in% input$options})
    shinyjs::toggle(id = "Ui2", condition = {2 %in% input$options})
  })
```

That said, I'm not sure why having neither box checked evaluates to `TRUE` in your case.

Comment: Just curious, why are the curly brackets necessary in the `condition =` argument?

Comment: @ForceLeft415, My understanding is that they're necessary to ensure that both lines are evaluated as a condition which can evaluate to a single `TRUE` or `FALSE` (or some other single outcome).